# Blinking Led on Raspberry Pi 2 code error

Tags: python, pi-2

I just started to use Raspberry pi. I am following [this guide](http://www.thirdeyevis.com/pi-page-2.php) at the moment.
At Blinking Light code I get syntaxerror : expected an indented block. What should I do to fix this?

The code :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library
import time ## Import 'time' library. Allows us to use 'sleep'

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 7 to OUT

##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(numTimes,speed):
for i in range(0,numTimes):## Run loop numTimes
print "Iteration " + str(i+1)## Print current loop
GPIO.output(7,True)## Switch on pin 7
time.sleep(speed)## Wait
GPIO.output(7,False)## Switch off pin 7
time.sleep(speed)## Wait
print "Done" ## When loop is complete, print "Done"
GPIO.cleanup()

## Ask user for total number of blinks and length of each blink
iterations = raw_input("Enter total number of times to blink: ")
speed = raw_input("Enter length of each blink(seconds): ")

## Start Blink() function. Convert user input from strings to numeric data types and pass to Blink() as parameters
Blink(int(iterations),float(speed))
```

Comment: The error would be "indented block" - you need to paste the code with leading spaces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I fixed the typo in question.

Comment: @Milliways how should it be after putting spaces. Things I tried didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it is copy-paste what makes it to lose its leading spaces. But still there are other errors. For solving these I put pharantesis for print functions and changing raw_input to input and it worked.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library
import time ## Import 'time' library. Allows us to use 'sleep'

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 7 to OUT

##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(numTimes,speed):
    for i in range(0,numTimes):## Run loop numTimes
        print ("Iteration " + str(i+1))## Print current loop
        GPIO.output(7,True)## Switch on pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)## Wait
        GPIO.output(7,False)## Switch off pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)## Wait
    print ("Done") ## When loop is complete, print "Done"
    GPIO.cleanup()

## Ask user for total number of blinks and length of each blink
iterations = input("Enter total number of times to blink: ")
speed = input("Enter length of each blink(seconds): ")

## Start Blink() function. Convert user input from strings to numeric data types and pass to Blink() as parameters
Blink(int(iterations),float(speed))
```

Comment: Python is much more widely used than the Raspberry Pi, so if you are learning it from a Pi specific guide that failed to mention it is whitespace sensitive, maybe you need to start with something else.  I'm not a user, but I notice python.org has a [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide).  This is probably worth working through before you do anything else.

Comment: The need to change raw_input to inpout is because you are using Python 2.7 code in Python 3